# use #() instead of (fn ...) in (sorted-map-by ...)

Tags: clojure, anonymous-function

I would like to translate the inner-function call in the following snippet, to one using the `#()` macro :

```
(let [m {:a 3, :b 2, :c 4, :x 9, :y 0, :z 5}]
  (into (sorted-map-by (fn [key1 key2]
                         (compare [(get m key2)]
                                  [(get m key1)]))) m))
```

I am a little bit confused on how I can accomplish that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside an anonymous function, the arguments are given by %1, %2... so you can use

```
(let [m {:a 3, :b 2, :c 4, :x 9, :y 0, :z 5}]
  (into (sorted-map-by #(compare (get m %2)
                                 (get m %1))) m))
```

note you don't need to wrap the compared values in a vector.